# Routing Based on HTTP

Tags: networking

I need a pointer in the right direction.

How do I route traffic by protocol.

I want all website (http) data going out interface 2 and all other data to work on the default gateway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to this question is Policy Based routing.

One can use IP Tables to mark packets.

One can then create rules to manage the routes of those packets.

For those who want to take look these following links helped me find a working solution:

https://serverfault.com/questions/733705/iproute-rt-table-and-mark-not-working-on-linux?newreg=e441de6f7bfe41d09cc0b430c9700d40

http://davidstangeby.blogspot.co.za/2012/10/port-based-routing-in-ubuntu.html